# ggplot geom_line(): problems colouring the lines by a factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping

I am trying to use ggplot to plot number of particles `dN`on the y axis against it's diameter `Dp` on the x axis. I have average values per month for a number of years.

My data is preprared in the long format. `month`, `year`, and `month_year`are factors, and `Dp` and `dN`are numeric. I have several years and several diameters (Dp).

```
 month year   Dp        dN month_year
    1 2006 3.16 4045.1261   1 / 2006
    2 2006 3.16 4447.6436   2 / 2006
    3 2006 3.16 6436.9364   3 / 2006
    4 2006 3.16 5632.1306   4 / 2006
    5 2006 3.16 4840.1949   5 / 2006
    6 2006 3.16 1480.3604   6 / 2006
    7 2006 3.16  928.6990   7 / 2006
    8 2006 3.16 1258.5296   8 / 2006
    9 2006 3.16  725.8546   9 / 2006
   10 2006 3.16  767.1681  10 / 2006
   11 2006 3.16  647.2605  11 / 2006
   12 2006 3.16  449.9188  12 / 2006
    1 2007 3.16  647.4428   1 / 2007
    2 2007 3.16  682.0582   2 / 2007
    3 2007 3.16  614.0303   3 / 2007`
```

I first did a plot colouring each line by the `month_year`variable:

```
ggplot(dataplot_m_y) +
  geom_line(aes(Dp, dN, colour = month_year), size=0.5)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_x_log10()
```

and I obtained this:

[image]
Every line corresponds to a month, and months are roughly coloured by the same colour (I mean, green colour corresponds approximately to the "Januaries" of all years, etc.). The legend is too long, so I didn't plot it.

Now, I would like to get exactly the same graph but with the same colour per month (and include the legend as well).

This is what I tried:

```
ggplot(dataplot_m_y) +
  geom_line(aes(Dp, dN, colour = month), size = 0.5)+
  scale_x_log10()
```

But I got this:

[image]

I also tried

```
ggplot(dataplot_m_y) +
  geom_line(aes(Dp, dN), colour = month, size = 0.5)+
  scale_x_log10()
```

But I got the following error: "Error in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'"

Could anybody help me solve this? Do I need to arrange the data differently?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `geom_line(aes(Dp, dN, colour=month, group=month_year)`?

Comment: is Dp variable always 3.16?

Comment: Thanks @drmariod, it worked!

Comment: @Antonis, no, variable Dp goes from 3.16 to 700... I just posted the first rows of my dataset.

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept my answer below. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution should be to define groups for the lines which are actually your `month_year` but color by `month`.

```
ggplot(dataplot_m_y) +
  geom_line(aes(Dp, dN, colour=month, group=month_year), size=0.5)+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_x_log10()
```